# Wire ceiling fan switch with remote control to always on

Tags: ceiling-fan, dimmer-switch, home-automation, smart-switch

How can I wire the switch of a remote controlled ceiling fan to always on so it can only be controlled with the remote.
I basically want to have a smart RF controller (BOND) be able to control the light and fan, but also have a smart dimmer switch trigger commands on BOND to control the same.

Comment: A lot will depend on the design of the fan. Do you already have the fan? If so, make & model would help.

Comment: This is a bad idea.  Leave the manual switch in place and just teach people in your house not to turn it off -- or get one of those "lockout" covers so it can't easily be accessed.  I guarantee at some date you will want to kill power to the mounting fixture (not just to the fan/light internals)

Comment: @CarlWitthoft thanks for the reply, is it a bad idea because it would break things, or that it won't work, or just because of the day I might want to actually kill it. I do intend to have a switch, but the switch won't be physically wired to the light, it will be in the expected wall, but instead of physically switching off, it would be a smart switch that tells BOND remote to turn on/off the fan/lights. About what you said of covering it, I'm precisely trying to avoid having people at home changing their routine. Thank you!

Comment: @manassehkatz-ReinstateMonica I already have the fan installed, trying to make it "smart". It's this one https://www.homedepot.com/p/Home-Decorators-Collection-Greco-III-52-in-LED-Indoor-Brushed-Nickel-Ceiling-Fan-with-Light-Kit-and-Remote-Control-YG354-BN/205299535. Thank you

Comment: My point is that a physical switch cuts the "live" power feed at the switch, while any other system leaves a live feed at the mounting box for the fan, which is less safe if you ever want to service the fan, or replace the fan, etc.

Comment: Got you, that makes sense, ok, any idea how to do what I want with the smart switch?